# https://gatorinsurances.com working but https://www.gatorinsurances.com not working

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I've just install SSL for the first time.  I've gotten a problem, `https://gatorinsurances.com` will resolve but `https://www.gatorinsurances.com` will not resolve.

My `.htaccess` code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

    # Force https and remove www
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gatorinsurances.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # BEGIN WordPress
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Start by reading the error message.  You need an SSL certificate.

Comment: How do you expect us to magically know what is wrong on your systems? How should we know your setup? How should we guess what your http servers error log files contain?

Comment: Looks like you need to get a wildcard cert.

Comment: You can't rewrite the secure request with the incorrect domain. It would need to connect first, the browser will fail it because the cert doesnt match.

Comment: www. is a sub domain like hello.yourdomain.com is the same domainlevel like www.yourdomain.com . If you complete website is not working start by checking your DNS. If only your SSL is not working on subdomains than you need a wildcard SSL. I recomment you using cloudflare. Everything you need is included in the free plan

Comment: Both names **resolve** fine, as in their are mapped to some IP. So the problem is not on the adressing part, but on the HTTP/HTTPS level  and what happens when you hit the webserver. You are dealing with HTTPS URLs but you show nothing about TLS from your Apache configuration file...